# Making PDO Database Connection available in controllers and models

Tags: mysql, pdo, connection

right now, I am kinda frustrated and I hope someone can help me and point me into the right direction.

I have an "old" project which uses the mysql statements for connection to database, etc.

Within this project I have the following:

An index file containing

```
*
* load configuration and connect to database
*/
$projectConfiguration = new projectConfiguration();
$dbconnect = $projectConfiguration->connect($projectConfiguration->databaseHost, $projectConfiguration->databaseName, $projectConfiguration->databaseUser, $projectConfiguration->databasePass);

// load controller
$ReqMod = FatFramework\Functions::getRequestParameter("mod");
if (!$ReqMod) {
$ReqMod = FatFramework\Functions::getRequestParameter("controller");
}
$module = ($ReqMod) ? $ReqMod : 'default';
```

In this style I call the views and actions in classes, like SaveAction()

Using mysql always made it very simple to use this database connection in the models called by the controllers like

```
public function loadCustomersList($sAdditionalWhere = false)
{
    $sQuery = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE 1 ";
    if ($sAdditionalWhere) {
        $sQuery .= "AND " . $sAdditionalWhere . " ";
    }
    $sQuery .= "ORDER BY company";
    $sql = mysql_query($sQuery);
    while (($customer = mysql_fetch_object($sql)) != false) {
        $aCustomers[] = $customer;
    }
    return $aCustomers;
}
```

I want to totally refractor this project and use PDO. I tried for the last 4 hours to find a solution, but I can't figure out how to make it work.

I think I don't need an extra dbconnect class since PDO is a class itself, am I right?

In the new index file I tried the following:

```
$db = new database();
try{
    $dbc = new PDO($db->get_DbConSettings());
    $dbc->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $e)
{
    echo 'Verbindung fehlgeschlagen: '.$e->getMessage();
}
```

But with this $dbc will not available in controllers or models. It there a way to make it available there? If not, what is the best solution? 
Do I have to make a database connection in every model?

An other issue I have with this is:
    $db->get_DbConSettings()
in 
    $dbc = new PDO

gives back

```
'mysql:host=127.0.0.1; dbname=c1virtbkk', 'root', '123'

($dbc = new PDO('mysql:host=127.0.0.1; dbname=c1virtbkk', 'root', '123');)
```

I cannot connect to the database. I get the following:

```
Verbindung fehlgeschlagen: could not find driver
```

If I don't use $db->get_DbConSettings and put the required information manually in, I don't get any error and can do queries. Any hints?

Help is really appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Mark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely don't create a new PDO connection in each model. Creating MySQL database connections is fairly quick, but there's still some overhead to doing so. You want to reuse a connection throughout your request. If nothing else, it allows you to share a transaction across multiple models.

Some frameworks store shared resource objects in a "registry" class which is a singleton key-value store. It's not really much more than a global hash array, but making it a class makes the registry itself more easily tested with PHPUnit. See https://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.registry.using.html for an example of a registry.

You're right that PDO is a class, even though it's implemented as a C extension instead of a PHP class. But it's a class, and `new PDO(...)` returns an object of that class.

One reason to create a db class of your own is to help you in unit-testing, because you could create a mock object for your db class so you can test your other classes (even model classes) without needing a live database connection. Your db class could extend or else contain a PDO object.

Your issue about the error "could not find driver" is probably because the PDO driver for mysql is not installed. PDO is one PHP extension, and then there's a separate extension for each brand of SQL database. You can confirm this with:

```
$ php -i

...lots of output...

PDO

PDO support => enabled
PDO drivers => mysql, odbc, sqlite

pdo_mysql

PDO Driver for MySQL => enabled
Client API version => mysqlnd 5.0.11-dev - 20120503 - $Id: 76b08b24596e12d4553bd41fc93cccd5bac2fe7a $

...more output for other extensions...
```

Note that PDO tells me which drivers I have installed: mysql, odbc, and sqlite.

So you need to install pdo_mysql. I'm not sure what OS you're on, but I'm often on CentOS Linux or Ubuntu Linux. The pdo_mysql is available as a separate package via yum or apt.

---

Re your comment:

Okay, here's an example of a registry:

```
class registry {
  protected static $items = array();

  public static get($key) {
    return isset(self::$items[$key])?
      self::$items[$key] : null;
  }

  public static set($key, $object) {
    self::$items[$key] = $object;
  }
}
```

In your controller initial code, you'd create a database object and store it in the registry:

```
$projectConfiguration = new projectConfiguration();
$dbconnect = $projectConfiguration->connect(
  $projectConfiguration->databaseHost, 
  $projectConfiguration->databaseName,
  $projectConfiguration->databaseUser,
  $projectConfiguration->databasePass);

registry::set('db', $dbconnect);
```

Then in your model class methods (or anywhere you need the database), get the db object from the registry and use it:

```
public function loadCustomersList($sAdditionalWhere = false)
{
    $sQuery = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE 1 ";
    if ($sAdditionalWhere) {
        $sQuery .= "AND " . $sAdditionalWhere . " ";
    }
    $sQuery .= "ORDER BY company";

    $db = registry::get('db');
    $stmt = $db->query($sQuery);
    $aCustomers = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $aCustomers;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the detailed information. I have trouble to understand the first two paragraphs but I will figure it out  Can I ask for a outrages request: could you provide an example for the registry? The Zend page confused me 

Comment: And again thank you! I will try this as soon as possible. Regarding the driver issue: I checked the phpinfo () and PDO MySQL is enabled. What confuses me is, that I only get this error if I use $db->get_DbConSettings() in $dbc = new PDO. If I write the necessary information directly into new PDO  (...), I don't get the error.

Comment: Then I would guess that your get_DbConSettings() function is not creating the PDO object with the right arguments. Review the documentation for the correct arguments to the PDO constructor.